# Creating a New Animation Clip in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to know how to make a simple animation video by using the unity game engine by using Animator Component, Animator Controller, Animation Clips.

Comment: Did you try googling the exact same question, there are lots of tutorials there

Answer (score 0):

My personal best way of doing so is selecting all the sprites you wish to animate at the hirerchy and dragging them to the editor scene.
Good luck!